# Delete all from string except a special word

Tags: java, string

Let's say I have a string like this:

```
String test = "hfikoebndolahsdHEL123LOkjahhsdqhuihs";
```

And then I want to delete all except the "HEL123LO" BUT the number could be like 653 and it wont delete it anyway. Is that possible? 
I hope you understand me!

Thanks in advance.

(Sorry for bad english).

Comment: Could there be multiple versions of HEL*LO in your input?  If yes, do you want to keep all of them?

Comment: Is aHEL13LObHEL14LOc a possible input?  If yes, do you want the result to be HEL12LO, HEL14LO or HEL13LOHEL14LO?

Comment: For my use I only need the last one :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your `String` is going to be of the kinds that you have mentioned, `"hfikoebndolahsdHEL123LOkjahhsdqhuihs"` with the likes of just the number changes in between, and you want to retain `HEL123LO` and rest of the letters are of the kind like in your example, you could do a simple substring. I know this may not be the best solution, but just suggesting an alternative.

```
test = test.substring(test.indexOf("H"),(test.lastIndexOf("O")+1));
```

Comment: You're kidding right? Your code would keep all of this input: `"HkjshdfshhsdkjhfO"`. No good.

Comment: @Bohemian I have explicitly mentioned in my answer that if the `String` is going to be of the kinds the OP has mentioned,with the surrounding letters being of the kind like in the example given by the OP(ie small case). That said, I never said this was "THE" solution. I just said it's an alternative to the specific case that the OP has put forward. :-)

Comment: Thanks! Work really great for my use. :)

Comment: This is a solution that only works for a very narrow range of cases: eg `"abcHOdef" --> "HO"`, `"abcH123456Odef" --> "H123465O"`, `"ghiHabcHEL123LOdefOxyz" --> "HabcHEL123LOdefO"` none of which seem to be what the question asks for. It is what is called a "brittle" solution.

Answer (score 14):

Use the [`String.replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method with the right regex.

```
test = test.replaceAll(".*(HEL\\d{3}LO).*", "$1");
```

This regex matches the whole input and replaces it with the matched group (group number 1).

Comment: This will keep only one instance.  Not clear from the question if there could be multiple ones and if yes, whether to keep all

Comment: @Attila Fair point, but the title of the question says "**a** special word", so I assumed just one. It becomes a little more complicated if keeping multiples - not nearly as elegant.